# Use of Undeclared identifier Update

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode

I have been following a tutorial, and I am struggling to implement the code correctly. I have little knowledge of Objective-C, and another user had an error in the step prior to this one, but their solution provided no assistance. The entire code for this project is posted below, including where the issue is occurring.

Cheers for the help.

```
-(id) init
{
if( (self=[super init])) {

    _batchNode = [CCSpriteBatchNode batchNodeWithFile:@"Sprites.pvr.ccz"]; // 1
    [self addChild:_batchNode]; // 2
    [[CCSpriteFrameCache sharedSpriteFrameCache] addSpriteFramesWithFile:@"Sprites.plist"]; // 3

    _ship = [CCSprite spriteWithSpriteFrameName:@"SpaceFlier_sm_1.png"];  // 4
    CGSize winSize = [CCDirector sharedDirector].winSize; // 5
    _ship.position = ccp(winSize.width * 0.1, winSize.height * 0.5); // 6
    [_batchNode addChild:_ship z:1]; // 7
    // 1) Create the CCParallaxNode
    _backgroundNode = [CCParallaxNode node];
    [self addChild:_backgroundNode z:-1];

    // 2) Create the sprites we'll add to the CCParallaxNode
    _spacedust1 = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"bg_front_spacedust.png"];
    _spacedust2 = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"bg_front_spacedust.png"];
    _planetsunrise = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"bg_planetsunrise.png"];
    _galaxy = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"bg_galaxy.png"];
    _spacialanomaly = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"bg_spacialanomaly.png"];
    _spacialanomaly2 = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"bg_spacialanomaly2.png"];

    // 3) Determine relative movement speeds for space dust and background
    CGPoint dustSpeed = ccp(0.1, 0.1);
    CGPoint bgSpeed = ccp(0.05, 0.05);

    // 4) Add children to CCParallaxNode
    [_backgroundNode addChild:_spacedust1 z:0 parallaxRatio:dustSpeed positionOffset:ccp(0,winSize.height/2)];
    [_backgroundNode addChild:_spacedust2 z:0 parallaxRatio:dustSpeed positionOffset:ccp(_spacedust1.contentSize.width,winSize.height/2)];
    [_backgroundNode addChild:_galaxy z:-1 parallaxRatio:bgSpeed positionOffset:ccp(0,winSize.height * 0.7)];
    [_backgroundNode addChild:_planetsunrise z:-1 parallaxRatio:bgSpeed positionOffset:ccp(600,winSize.height * 0)];
    [_backgroundNode addChild:_spacialanomaly z:-1 parallaxRatio:bgSpeed positionOffset:ccp(900,winSize.height * 0.3)];
    [_backgroundNode addChild:_spacialanomaly2 z:-1 parallaxRatio:bgSpeed positionOffset:ccp(1500,winSize.height * 0.9)];
    // Add to end of init method
    [self scheduleUpdate];

    // Add new update method
    - (void)update:(ccTime)dt{

        CGPoint backgroundScrollVel = ccp(-1000, 0);
        _backgroundNode.position = ccpAdd(_backgroundNode.position, ccpMult(backgroundScrollVel, dt));

    }
    }
return self;
}
```

Error Context

```
 // Add to end of init method
 [self scheduleUpdate];

 // Add new update method
 - (void)update:(ccTime)dt {

CGPoint backgroundScrollVel = ccp(-1000, 0);
_backgroundNode.position = ccpAdd(_backgroundNode.position, ccpMult(backgroundScrollVel, dt));

 }
```

The line causing the Error

```
  - (void)update:(ccTime)dt {
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Objective-C you can not give definition of a method inside the method. So you should put the definition of the method `update` outside of the method `init`.

```
-(id) init
{
    if( (self=[super init]))
    {
         //Implementation of init...
          [self scheduleUpdate];
    }
    return self;
}

// Add new update method
 - (void)update:(ccTime)dt
{
     CGPoint backgroundScrollVel = ccp(-1000, 0);
     _backgroundNode.position = ccpAdd(_backgroundNode.position, ccpMult(backgroundScrollVel, dt));
 }
```

Comment: Thanks to both of you, i didn't understand how to insert the code and this has fixed it

Answer (score 1):

You can't declare methods inside of other methods. They have to be separate.